# How to highlight a specific word in html based newsletter?

Tags: html, highlight, newsletter

I would like to ask you the following: 
I have a newsletter that is html based, the newsletter is linked to articles that are automatically added. These articles show as:

```
Title:
Article 1 pub date
description
Article 2 pub date
description and so on
```

I would like to highlight certain words in the description of the articles or in the titles. E.g "Test". (or in other words add a rule that will make sure that everytime articles are loaded in the newsletter and if that specific word is present in one of the articles that it gets highlighted. I hope you could help me with some tips as to where I should put certain code in the part below or somewhere else (the html code has  and  and ).

Thanks a bunch.

The part that makes sure that articles are loaded is as follows:

---

```
<!-- This part generates the articles -->
    <xsl:template match="story" mode="article">
    <xsl:if test="related">
            <tr>
                <td><a><xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="storyid"/></xsl:attribute></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 9pt; text-decoration: none;"><a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="weburl"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="titel"/></a> - <xsl:value-of select="source_lang"/>
<xsl:if test="type='WEBARTICLE' and weburl!=''"> online</xsl:if></td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:if test="snippet!=''">

            <tr>
                <td style="line-height: 5px;"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text></td>
            </tr>
                         <tr><td style="font-size: 9pt; text-decoration: none;">
                              ...<xsl:apply-templates select="snippet"/>...</td>
            </tr>
                      </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Try wrapping your content in `<mark>` tag which you need to highlight

Comment: I am quite new to html (actually very new), <mark> where would I need to add that part in the code as provided?

Comment: Please show some samples of newsletter

Comment: @Gru I seem to not be allowedto add screenshots, cause of my point average. And I do not know how else to send you the sample of the newsletter.

Comment: anyone please? :(

Comment: can we use jQuery here..? And in which line your description is loading...?

Comment: @gru thanks for your reply, I will close this question since it is no longer necessary to highlight specific words. Thanks again. Have a great day.

Comment: hehehe..! alright. happy coding </>